# wordpress database returns A's

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I moved my friends Wordpress site from one host to another using these steps:
- Export current database
- Create new database and import SQL data
- Move all files
- Update DNS and @ records on domain

DNS are propagated, database connection succeeds, files are accessible, database data seams alright, but everywhere there should be data from the database printed out, only an 'A' is displayed. Of course this affecte almost all content, menus, images, links etc...

I'm sure it's a simple thing to fix but I don't know where to look, any clue?
The new host is a Dreamhost happy hosting, maybe it's related to it, haven't worked much with dreamhost yet.

You can view the problem here: http://www.circuit72.com/

Thanks

Comment: Search in your code for img src="a"

Comment: that is bizarre. Did you perform a search and replace on the database after you reimported it? Second, did you check the theme? It should say something like `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>` for the links. Is that still there, or does it say `<a href="a">`?

Comment: is there a left over debug function kicking in?

Comment: Problem was the way the theme's page builder was saving data, it could not be moved over sql regularly. The solution was to use the theme's EXPORT CONTENT fonction and import it back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the way the theme's page builder was saving data, it could not be moved over sql regularly. The solution was to use the theme's EXPORT CONTENT fonction and import it back again.